# My Camera activity keeps force closing onSurfaceDestroyed

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview, forceclose

SO guys I am making a Camera Application and I don't understand all the code but most of it. I copied some of the code from the net. My activity keeps force closing onSurfaceDestroyed method. I can't tell why it keeps closing when I click a picture. Because when I click a picture I start an Intent to go to a new activity. That is when the surface gets destroyed. Btw my surface is a relative layout on which my camera preview is taking place. The error is taking place in the ShowCamera class in the OnSurfaceDestroyed method. I can see the preview. The app closes when I try to click a pic.

This is my code. From my MainActivity.java I send the code below in the onCreateMethod

```
Camera frontCam = Camera.open(1) // 1 is for front cam
Show Camera showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, frontCam);
```

From the MainActivity.java I send the code below onCapture of a picture

```
private PictureCallback capturedIt = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        if (bitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not taken",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "taken",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent viewerIntent = new Intent("com.tyrone.mirrorapp.AFTERCAPTURE");
            viewerIntent.setClass(MainActivity.this, afterCapture.class);
            Bundle bitmapBundle = new Bundle();
            bitmapBundle.putByteArray("clickedBitmap", data);
            viewerIntent.putExtras(bitmapBundle);
            startActivityForResult(viewerIntent,0);
        }
        cameraObject.release();
    }

};
```

This is my ShowCamera.java class below

```
public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder holdMe;
   Camera theCamera;

public ShowCamera(Context context,Camera camera) {
      super(context);
      theCamera = camera;
      holdMe = getHolder();
      holdMe.addCallback(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int width, int height) {
       theCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);//cz the fron cam doesn't adjust.
       theCamera.startPreview();
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
       try {
        theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
       theCamera.setPreviewCallback(null); 
       theCamera.stopPreview();
       theCamera.release();
       theCamera = null;
   }

}
```

My activity keeps force closing on destroy of the activity. Any Idea what the reason could be?
P.S. :  I'm not entirely sure it force closes onSurfaceDestroyed. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank You

part of my log file

```
11-18 20:30:31.877: I/SurfaceView(21648): Callback --> surfaceCreated
11-18 20:30:31.877: I/SurfaceView(21648): surfaceCreated callback +
11-18 20:30:31.877: D/setting preview display(21648): getting Ready
11-18 20:30:31.879: D/AndroidRuntime(21648): Shutting down VM
11-18 20:30:31.879: W/dalvikvm(21648): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a00c98)
11-18 20:30:31.879: W/dalvikvm(21648): threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
11-18 20:30:31.879: W/System.err(21648): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
11-18 20:30:31.880: W/System.err(21648):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Native Method)
11-18 20:30:31.880: W/System.err(21648):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Camera.java:580)
11-18 20:30:31.880: W/System.err(21648):    at com.tyrone.mirrorapp.ShowCamera.surfaceCreated(ShowCamera.java:66)
11-18 20:30:31.880: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:662)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:256)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at com.tyrone.mirrorapp.ShowCamera.onWindowVisibilityChanged(ShowCamera.java:98)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:8096)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1448)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
11-18 20:30:31.881: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
11-18 20:30:31.882: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
11-18 20:30:31.882: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
11-18 20:30:31.882: W/System.err(21648):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
11-18 20:30:31.882: W/System.err(21648):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
11-18 20:30:31.882: W/System.err(21648):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
11-18 20:30:31.882: W/System.err(21648):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-18 20:30:31.882: W/System.err(21648):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
11-18 20:30:31.882: W/System.err(21648):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 20:30:31.882: W/System.err(21648):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-18 20:30:31.883: W/System.err(21648):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
11-18 20:30:31.883: W/System.err(21648):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
11-18 20:30:31.883: W/System.err(21648):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 20:30:31.883: W/dalvikvm(21648): threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648): Process: com.tyrone.mirrorapp, PID: 21648
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Native Method)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Camera.java:580)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at com.tyrone.mirrorapp.ShowCamera.surfaceCreated(ShowCamera.java:66)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:662)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:256)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at com.tyrone.mirrorapp.ShowCamera.onWindowVisibilityChanged(ShowCamera.java:98)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:8096)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1448)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
11-18 20:30:31.885: E/AndroidRuntime(21648):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the log please :)

Comment: ok @VincentD. D but this is a new one. A new error. It happens at setPreviewCallback. Changed my code a bit.

Comment: Is your code in your post up to date and log up to date too?

Comment: Hi @VincentD. No the code is not updated. Can I send you the code through mail? Its really big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log states that the exception happens onSurfaceCreated. **theCamera** object is released before this callback is invoked. Please check where you release camera in your app. Maybe, you release it after you pass **frontCam** to **ShowCamera** constructor in `onCreate()`.

*OK, as you explained, this happens when you return to MainActivity from another one*. The common practice is to open camera in `onResume(`), and release in `onPause()`. It is also possible to open camera in `ShowCamera.surfaceCreated()`, and release (as in your code above) in `ShowCamera.surfaceDestroyed()`.

It is recommended to open camera in a background thread, but this involves more delicate scheduling of call to `Camera.setPreviewDisplay()`.

Comment: This happens only the second time the activity runs. That is when I go from the current activity(that works 1st time) to the next activity and return to the first activity(which doesn't work the second time). What could be the problem? I release the camera after the 1st time when shifting to the next activity. So what should I do when I get back to the 1st activity?

Comment: Usually, it is recommended to open camera in `onResume()`, and release in `onPause()` of the Activity or Fragment. If your activity launches another one, and then the user goes _back_, then `onCreate()` may be skipped. On the other hand, it may not. But `onResume()` will be invoked inevitably.

Comment: I had tried that before it din't help. So now I tried it again and it still didn't. I made like a thousand changes after the ones you suggested. I don't really know what I've done but I got it to work.  But anyway thanks alot for the help bro @AlexCohn. Will give you the green tick for your attempts to help.

Comment: and @AlexCohn if you need my entire activity files lemme know. Or anyone else reading this if y'all need help.

Comment: Glad if you can help me with this similar issue- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066510/camera-surfacedestroyed-gets-called-on-opening-a-share-windowfacebook-twitter